# Building & using ZeroMQ with Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, networking, zeromq, winsock

Anyone out there successfully building/using ZeroMQ under Windows (MSVC)?

I'm trying to build/use the current master in GitHub (https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq) which has Visual Studio projects as well as CMake files. I've built the CMake project (after fixing some issues in the MSVC specific stuff) which also builds all the tests but the tests fail the same way my simple test program does.

The first call to WinSock select() always results in WSAENOTSOCK and the app bails. I've now tried this on a 64bit Win7 and Win8 machines with both VS2010 and VS2013 for debug and release builds with no luck :(

I get similar aborts when trying to build against the pre-built binaries on the ZeroMQ site or building my own with the included Visual Studio project directories they include in the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation and a few hints from the mailing list the moral of the story is ZeroMQ, Windows and RealVNC don't mix.

If port 5905 is in use by anything else then ZeroMQ will crash under Windows (you can use netstat -a -b to check).

Although as a more general observation, ZeroMQ relying on hard coded ports to be free and not gracefully handling this case is less than ideal.

http://lists.zeromq.org/pipermail/zeromq-dev/2015-August/029451.html

Comment: Pull request for ZeroMQ has been accepted which fixes this issue. https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/pull/1543